# Передать сессию из всплывающего окна в родителя

Tags: сессия, ajax, php, cookie, javascript

Стоит такая задача: на произвольном сайте установлен js-код, который аяксом запрашивает сервер. В ответе выводится форма авторизации через соцсети типа Oauth2. Авторизация происходит во всплывающем окне. После авторизации окно закрывается и необходимо аяксом подгрузить данные уже авторизованного пользователя. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как из всплывающего окна передать id сессии в родительское. Авторизация происходит во всплывающем и следовательно, кука сохраняется тоже в нем. А из-за того, что окно запрашивается с другого домена, вытащить из него данные в родительское окно нельзя - Origins policy мешает.
Помогите найти выход.

Comment: Да выходов полно, передавать данные в БД, а потом от туда брать, либо JSом, записывать в глобальную переменную а потом брать.

Comment: неужели вы думаете, что я такой тупой, что эти элементарные варианты не заметил? Записывать в БД сессию, а потом брать? - а где ссылку на нее сохранять? Если 10 человек одновременно регятся - какую сессию из БД им вытаскивать? А насчет глобальной JS - вы сами-то уверены, что в разных окнах она сохраняет значение?

Comment: На самом  деле, я выход нашел - использовать postMessage

Comment: @ldanmer, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.